# Changing the value of an input inside a table cell in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get JQuery to renumber the 'Order' column after Sorting them. Here is the code:

```
// Sorting

    $(function() {

    $("#sortable").sortable({cursor: "move"});
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();

    });

    // Renumber

    $("#sortable").sortable({

        stop: function (event, ui){

            $(this).find('tr').each(function(i){

    // this is where the problem is:

                $(this).find('td:last').$(this).find('input').val(i+1);

            });

        }

    });
```

So, what is the proper way of getting the value field?

Comment: Add your html code.

Comment: Side note: `$(this).find('td:last').$(this)` doesn't make sense.  Not sure why you threw that extra `$(this)` in there

Comment: inside the ('td:last'), there is an input with a text type. I tried $child and it did not work.

Comment: Just take out the second `$(this)`.  `$(selector).find(selector).find(selector)` will perform the methods off of the results previously found.  There's no need to do anything extra.  The first find operates off of the first results, and the second find operates off the results of the previous find.

Comment: why not to write `$(this).find('td:last input').val...`?

Comment: or `$('td:last input', this)`, :)

Comment: It is still not working :/